# Does f.lux affect DirectX video games?

Tags: colors, directx, f.lux

Does [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) affect the color temperature of DirectX video games?

I appreciate what it does on the desktop, but I'm not sure if I want it on in a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indeed affects DirectX games. I checked the option to disable it for an hour, and about an hour into a fullscreen game, the color temperature dropped.

I can't demonstrate the effect with screenshots (both of the captures will have the intended temperatures), but I can show it with a camera:

[image: Flux off][image: Flux on]

Answer (score 3):

Easy to find out: set flux to an absurdly low temperature and start a game, it should be obvious.

Result: Yes, it does affect games (as it does movies, even with MadVR)

Answer (score 2):

f.lux doesn't affect *fullscreen* DirectX games. I just tested it on a fullscreen game myself.

Why? I don't know, but it may have to do with the fact that fullscreen DirectX games operate on a different principle than windowed DirectX games. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304669/why-direct3d-application-performs-better-in-full-screen-mode) for the technical details.

Comment: I just tested this again, and it's very clear to me that it does affect fullscreen games. Interestingly, I can't demonstrate it with screenshots, but it would be easy to see with a camera. Which game did you try it in?

Comment: Starcraft 2 running on Windows 8. In Fullscreen mode, the color temperature goes back to blinding white (I can tell because it burns my eyes). In Windowed mode, there is a *clear* reddish hue.

Comment: I just tried it in SCII and it seems this game is not affected. I guess it depends on the game, but I wonder how.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to depend on the game. I tested it with a Source engine game (Team Fortress 2 on Win 8.1) and it works with f.lux only in windowed mode, not fullscreen. Borderless windowed should also be a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

- Start the game up (fullscreen mode)
- Tab out then restart f.lux while the game is running.
- Working! Colour temperature now affects both in-game and desktop mode.

As simple as it is, enjoy it :D